# PHP SQLSRV Sql Azure, An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query

Tags: php, azure-sql-database

I am trying to make a simple select query from PHP application to sql azure. but it generates same error always. An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. I have deployed my php application by a web role and using windows PI.what I get form phpinfo(); shows that sqlsrv has been loaded and php is 5.3.13 but I dont know which version.  here is the query

```
 $login_query = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username = ? and password = ?";

 $params = array($username, $salted);

 $login_result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $login_query, $params);

 if ($login_result == false){
     //die(mysql_error());  commented
     echo $username;

     echo $password;

     echo "Errors:";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Now when I have tested same query goes well in my index.php but generates the error (invalid parameter ...) in session.php. very strange

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?